# Start Date should be todays date and end date should be todays date plus one month

Tags: powerbi

I have a requirement, Ii have date slicer i have created the date dimension

```
Start Date = CALENDAR (DATE ( 1900,1, 1), DATE (2025,12, 31))
```

Now I have kept the slicer for this it shows like this 1/1/1900 - 12/31/2025
but the end user want to see the start date with default todays date i.e. 01/02/2019 start date &  end date.JPG
and end date should show as 02/02/2019 instead of 12/31/2025.

Can anybody suggest me how can I approach this requirement?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're after.

If you're asking for to set a default value for a slicer, that's not possible yet. Upvote this at: [Slicer default selected values](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/19055692-slicer-default-selected-values)

Also, when you're using DATES, please use the right syntax, for example:

- dd.MM.yyyy
- yyyy.MM.dd

Other relevant information that could solve what I think you're after: https://www.fourmoo.com/2017/10/03/power-bi-did-you-know-all-power-bi-services-servers-are-in-utc-now-how-to-handle-it-for-dates-times/